# Rad studio not giving a platform to work with

Tags: installation, rad-studio

I have installed rad studio from a free trial, but after installation, it does not give me the option to pick a plateform like it does in online tutorials, the application doesn't even run.. it just shows a popup (image attached) and that's it.

I have tried reinstalling it, even downloading it all over again, but the same issue persists.[this is the the message I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9OKx.png)

[This is the window I should be getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6Iyc.png)
I have not change anything from the installation tutorial, I have no antivirus getting in the way either.